# Wake computer from sleep every hour?

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I need my computer to wake up from sleep, and go back to sleep, hourly.

Now i've created tasks in the Task Scheduler, and so far I haven't managed to get the exact behaviour i want.

To keep it simple, i want it to wake up, go back to sleep - and do that every hour.

I use Windows 10
Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Is there a reason https://superuser.com/questions/1196146/how-to-use-less-power-while-pc-is-on-24-7/1196229#1196229 doesn't work? Putting a computer to sleep and waking up will likely consume more power if you have that solution in effect.

Comment: You've asked for 'other software' This makes it off topic :( I suggest you edit your question to remove question (2) to help avoid your question being closed

Comment: Lchip haven't tried that but it says to put max processor to 5%...no way i can do that

Comment: @DenisDelinger you should try it before dismissing it. Of course you can raise the 5% to anything. A modern computer running windows 10 will still perform quite well with the 5% limit set. I tested it and I was able to game normally even, because gaming mostly uses the GPU. Rule of thumb. If you open task manager and you see the cpu usage is only a few % in use, (likely the case) you can easily set its cap very low.

Comment: lpchip no, its not

Comment: I'm envisioning the "do nothing" gadget, where you flip a switch to turn it on and a little hand pops out to flip the switch back off.  I imagine it would be possible to create a scheduled task that would reschedule itself and go back to sleep.  However, I can't imagine any way in which such a thing would accomplish a useful purpose.  Can you clarify the bigger picture of what you're trying to do?  The site's objective is to build a knowledge base of solutions to problems other people will also face.  It would be helpful to frame this in a way that it would be useful to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do some stuff in your way try creating **batch file**. For your second question I hope this may help you https://www.raymond.cc/blog/automatically-wake-up-from-windows-stand-by-and-hibernation/.

Comment: First of all, Welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but please do not provide answers that are only a hyperlink.  While the information may be valuable, if the source web page ever goes offline the answer is essentially useless.  Quote all of the pertinent excerpts from the article within your answer, then you can still provide the hyperlink to cite your source.   Please see the following article from our Help Center:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: To add to Run5k's comment, the second question was deleted, so the link is now irrelevant.  But your answer to the remaining portion of the question is to try creating a batch file.  The intention of answer posts is really to be actionable solutions.  Hinting at a vague direction to pursue might be useful to get someone started, but that is more appropriate as a comment (which requires a little more rep).  An answer would be an actual batch file that accomplishes what was asked.